# rangeなどで作成した変数を行列に変換したい

Tags: python, python3

```
for i in range(5)
```

で出力される

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

という結果を以下のように1行の行列に変換したいです。

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

rangeを使って連続した数値を持つリストを作成する、というご質問でしたら下記の方法が使えます。

```
list(range(5))
```

目的がリストではなくnumpyの行列でしたら、

```
import numpy
numpy.array(range(5))
```

といった方法があります。

---

追記2017/11/26

```
A=[]
idx=0
while idx<4:
    A.append(idx+1)
    idx += 1
print(A)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

a=0
for i in range(5):
    a = a+1
    print(a)
    
これのaを[1,2,3,4,5]としたい場合はどうすればよいですか？

Comment: `a = list()`として`a.append(i+1)`で要素をfor文の中で追加していくか、リスト内包表記`[i+1 for i in range(5)]`という方法などがあります。

Comment: 以下のような場合、[1,2,3,4]の行列に変換できなかったのですが、どのように変換すればよいですか？
A=0
while A<4:
    A = A+1
    print(A)

Comment: 何を試してどのような結果になったかを教えていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: >>>dkatoさん A=0
while A<4: A = A+1 print(A) こちらを入力して
1
2
3
4
が出力されました。
結果としては上記と同じように[1,2,3,4]を必要としています。

Comment: 以下のようなプログラムになります。

Comment: 追記する形でコードを書いて見ました。これのことでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。idxの値１ずつ増えていかずランダムのような値の場合で、(idx+1)が使えないような場合はどのようにしたらよろしいですか？

Comment: 内容が最初の質問と乖離してきているので、さらに聞きたい内容がある場合は別のスレッドを立ててください。